# Unity Firebase RealtimeDatabase GetValueAsync() does not return anything

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

The following code was executed properly with the **Firebase version 4.2**:

```
public void RetrieveSummary(Action<int[]> onRetrieve) {
    Debug.Log("FirebaseStorageService - Retrieving Summary from remote...");
    string referencePath = string.Format("users/{0}/sum", GetUserID());
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference(referencePath).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsCompleted) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            if (snapshot.Exists) {
                HammurabiAnalytics.LogCustomEvent("Download_Data_Size", "Summary_User_Data", snapshot.GetRawJsonValue().Length);
                Debug.Log("FirebaseStorageService - Raw Remote Summary Data: " + snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
                int[] summaryData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[]>(snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
                Debug.Log("FirebaseStorageService - Retrieving Summary from remote - DONE");
                onRetrieve(summaryData);
            } else {
                Debug.Log("FirebaseStorageService - User Summary Data is missing!");
                onRetrieve(new int[4]);
            }
        } else {
            Debug.LogError("FirebaseStorageService - RetrieveSummary has failed!");
            onRetrieve(new int[4]);
        }
    });
}
```

By properly I mean **ContinueWith** was executed and I was able to continue the process with the log messages and etc. After updating the **Firebase version to 5.2.1**, I am not able to continue.

*To detail the issue, I can say that the code block inside ContinueWith does not get called when there is no data on the reference. If I create a data on the reference, retrieving works properly. I also cannot add a dummy data.*

I could not find a workaround either, this blocks me too bad. Any idea? Any workaround? Any solution to the root cause?

***Firebase : 5.2.1,  Unity : 2017.2***

Comment: When you say it fails, what do you mean? Do you get an error, if so what is it?

Comment: It does not ContinueWith. I do not get any errors in logcat

Comment: Do you mean the code within ContinueWith does not get called? I don't know coding for Unity but are there other code blocks within ContinueWith?

Comment: Exactly! The code block inside ContinueWith does not get called.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what's going on here. First, verify that your first debug log statement is not getting called. I think it probably is. What is most likely happening is that `task.Result` is `null`, resulting in an exception being thrown, preventing the rest of your log functions from executing. Because of the way the `ContinueWith` works, the exception just gets silently consumed.

You can fix this by checking if the task faulted before you get the result from it by using `task.IsFaulted`. Being completed just means its done running, not that it completed successfully, and if it was unsuccessful the Result doesn't get populated.